# Is Static local variable in vb.net unsuitable for disposable objects?

Tags: vb.net, dispose, local-variables

Are local [**`Static`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx) variables a no-go for disposable objects? The main problem with this case: `Dispose()` might never get called.

Example:

```vb
Sub DrawText(text As String, fontFamily As Font)
    Static cachedFont As Font = Nothing
    If cachedFont Is Nothing OrElse fontFamily <> cachedFont.Family Then
        cachedFont = New Font(fontFamily)
    EndIf
    'now draw text using cachedFont
End Sub
```

**Is such cases, is the only way to convert local static variable into local class variable** (which is being disposed in `Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)`)?

Comment: In my opinion, I'd put it as a member on the class anyway, for clarity, disposable or not.

Comment: @JamesThorpe – clarity can be discussed. Sometimes is it better to have trivial variable in one place than to see it scattered around the class (constructor + method where it is needed + disposer).

Comment: Indeed - hence my opinion :)  If it's something that lives with the class, it deserves to be on the class.

Comment: Blindly micro-optimizing code is never not a mistake.  Your static variable accomplishes nothing, fonts are already cached.  Use the Using statement.

Comment: @HansPassant – your note that fonts are already cached helped for that specific case. I couldn't see it in .net docs. Are they cached in Windows or in .net? And yes, `Using` statement is what I'm actually using at the moment.

Comment: Winforms caches them internally.  But that's irrelevant, the operative word here is "blindly".  Micro-optimize when a profiler tells you that it is good idea.

Comment: @HansPassant – technically, I can only agree with micro-optimization point. But IMHO the most important optimization today is for human readability (but I mean overall "gettability"), not for machines – they are fast enough. Hence, sometimes it could be better to have trivial variable usage completely in one place. But this approach has also its limits, as apparent from this Q&A.

Comment: Hmm, this code is the antipode to readability.  You'll owe whomever reads it twenty minutes of their life, spent on trying to figure out why you don't dispose when the family changes and what is going to happen when you stop calling DrawText.  Just don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are a no-go if you want them to be disposed.

`Static` local variables are compiled to

- in a `Shared` procedure:

  - to `Shared` field variables at class level
- in a non-`Shared` instance method:

  - to instance field variables at class level

...which name is derived from the method name and the variable name to ensure that it's unique per type.

The `Shared` variables are never be disposed for the lifetime of an application because you can dispose only instances.   The instance variables are disposed when you call `instance.Dispose` or use the `Using`-statement.

But the garbage collector in the CLR does not (and cannot) dispose of unmanaged objects. So the problem is that you can't dispose these objects from `Dispose` because it's out of scope as local variable. So if you need to clean up unmanaged resources in `Dispose` you can't do that with `Static` local variables because you can't access them.

Worth reading:

- [Object Lifetime: How Objects Are Created and Destroyed (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hks5e2k6.aspx)
- [Static (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx)

Comment: Maybe you can correct last paragraph: `Static` and `Shared` are *not  equal* in their scope. Only `Shared` value is one per type. But `Static` value is one per class instance. You can see it in **Behavior** pargaph in [MSDN article on Static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx). This might somewhat change also your explanation of what compiler actually does.

Comment: @miroxlav: `Static`(in VB.NET) is the same as `Shared` but only used for local variables. Yes, they have  a different scope. You cannot access a `Static` variable from outside of the method or from another class. But they are equal after compilation. What happens behind the scenes is that the compiler will create a new static field variable in the type for every `Static` variable. It's name will be derived from the method-name + variable-name.

Comment: @miroxlav: Let me read that article first, maybe i was wrong ;)

Comment: While I understand your explanation, it is only explaining the case of VB  `Static` in `Shared` procedure. MSDN continues, I quote: `When you declare a static variable in a procedure that isn't Shared, only one copy of the variable is available for each instance of the class.`. Concept of VB `Static` is a bit different from what one would intuitively think. So may I assume that `Static` variable in *non-shared* sub will be **auto-disposed** along with its class instance? Hence, it is no big issue in having disposable variable in it? This could change things a little (including the answer).

Comment: @miroxlav: yes, i think that's true. All non-shared method's `static` variables are garbage collected when the instance is no longer refernced and the GC is active. But the problem is that you can't dispose this object from `Dispose` because it's out of scope as local variable. So if you need to clean up Uumanaged resources in dispose you can't do that with static local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Sad to say it, after checking with VS2015's [Memory Usage Tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/04/02/diagnosing-memory-issues-with-the-new-memory-usage-tool-in-visual-studio/) I can confirm that Static instances are **NOT** GC'ed when closing/disposing for example a form using them.

To test it create a project with two forms. In Form2's `Form2_Load` event declare and add some fonts to a Static `List(Of Font)`. In `Form1_Load` create and show an instance of Form2.
Execute the project using `Debug->Performance and Diagnostics` menu option, use `Memory Usage` behavior.
You'll get both forms popping up.
Close Form2. Click `Force GC` button in `Memory Usage Tool` window and take a memory snapshot.
Close Form1 to stop execution.

Click `nnnn objects` link in Snapshot 1, a new window will open. Uncheck `Collapse small objects` in upper right dropdown button of that window.
Type 'font' in search box and you'll see all those Fonts remaining in memory.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort to test this and share your findings.